# Unable to Save File in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

(SOLVED)

I am encountering an issue in Visual Studio 2022 where I am unable to save a file after editing it. Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

- Open Visual Studio 2022 and create a new project or open an existing one.
- Make changes to a file within the project.
- Tried to save the changes by selecting "Save" or pressing Ctrl+S, but saving window stays the same and does not react.
- After checking if maybe it was already saved in the file explorer it still says the old changing date, which means that nothing has been saved.
- I tried compiling the code too, but it fails and the save window of the file which I tried to save pops up.

At this point, nothing happens. The file does not save, and there are no error messages or indications of any issues. It seems like the save operation is not being executed or is being blocked somehow.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Restarting Visual Studio and reopening the solution.
- Creating a new project and attempting to save files within it.
- Checking for any read-only or write-protection settings on the file or its parent folder.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 and have not experienced this issue before. Other file operations, such as opening and editing files, are working fine. This problem is specific to the save operation.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem in Visual Studio 2022? Are there any known workarounds or solutions for this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Saving window:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pkcv.png)

Comment: after your second step the file is already saved, what do you expect to happen from saving it again right after it has already been saved? Why is it a problem?

Comment: A misbehaving virus scanner would be my first guess

Comment: I tried to click on save it just stays open like I never pressed save (It literally ignores).

Comment: when there are no modifications to be saved then what you describe is expected behavior. What exactly do you expect to happen when you save the file the second time?

Comment: There are changes in the file I want to save.

Comment: in your quesiton you write: 1) create a file 2) modify it 3) save if (works) 4) save it again, does not work. When you modify the file between 3 and 4, you need to say that. Currently the question is unclear.

Comment: Oh okay i think you missunderstood it and maybe I wrote it confusing XD, I tried to save it again after it failed once

Comment: "...I am unable to save a file after initially saving it. " means: You were able to save it once but not afterwards. If you cannot save the file at all, thats not what you write in the question

Comment: How do you know that the file "does not save" ? "it just stays open" is normal.

Comment: Because every time I start to compile smth it forces me to save the file and the changing date stays the same

Comment: You should explain that in the post. From other comments, your exact sequence of operations is unclear (and from your recent reply, it is not the real one).

Comment: What do you call "saving window" ? When you Save, no window pops up.

Comment: I will post a picture under the question

Comment: @niki.orihatza On your screen shot, the file name on which you try to save is wrong. It cannot contain the character `*`
. But I don't know why you are trying to save under a different name. Simply running a build automatically saves all source files anyway.

Comment: @niki.orihatza The 'saving window' only appears because you do not have permissions to save the modified file. VS is asking you if you want to save this file somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify a read-only file (in a system folder). You should not do that.

Also observe that the filename is not valid in the "Save File As" dialog (extension *).

Comment: thanks, didn't even noticed that it was a file from the system folder :D